# Redshift: How to insert two columns on the same row into a single column in a secondary table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have `TableA` containing two columns `col1` and `col2`. I want to query all results in `col1` and `col2` and insert them into a new `TableB newCol`.

I am hitting a road block on whether I can do this with one query:

```
Insert into TableB
(newCol)
select SOMEFUNCTION(col1,col2)
from TableA;
```

Hence if `TableA` results in the rows:

```
{1,2},{3,4}
```

When inserted into `TableB` the rows would be:

```
{1},{2},{3},{4}
```

Can you tell me if there is a function represented by `SOMEFUNCTION()` that will do the trick in Redshift?

Comment: what type are the columns?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean by `{1,2},{3,4}`, and whether this is one row or multiple rows. Could you please edit your question and provide a sample with a few rows of actual (fake) examples? Please show samples of both the source data and the results you are seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer here is to listagg a concat of col1 and Col2.

listagg(col1 || ',' || col2, ',')

The trick here is to make it a two step process. Insert the concat into a sorted column of a temp table before running the listagg() function.

It's not a single function, but will solve the immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Split_part` function could be used in this case.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html

Your query should be something like,

`Insert into TableB (newCol)select Split_part(col1,'\,', Max_size_number#) from TableA;`

Let me know if I misunderstood your use case. I could reattempt the answer.